# Remove existing data from localStorage on browser crash

Tags: javascript, request, local-storage, service-worker

I am trying to implement a queue based processes implementation. I have a react component that sends a post request to the server and on changing the status in the backend, starts to upload files to s3. In each process there are multiple files (of the order of 50 files to 100k files). On page refresh the upload process stops. Also this can happen in multiple tabs. The queue system is for that. Suppose the user starts an upload process in one tab and then opens another tab and creates another process and then third process in the third tab, then the second one will start only after the first process is complete and third one after the second one is complete and so on. For this, I have created a list of `process ids` in `localStorage` and in `setInterval` I keep on checking if the first element in the array is the present process id and if it is then I continue with the uploading else I keep checking it every 1 sec. After every file is uploaded, I `shift` the array.

My problem is that if there is a system crash there are orphan ids in the array and because of that my new processes get stuck. Is there any way to know if there are any requests coming from the process and if there are no requests then remove that id from the array in localStorage so that next process id becomes the first in the array and so on, so that I can remove the orphan process ids and starts the new relevant process? I have to implement this using storages but there is no way for me to know whether a browser crash happened. Also if user opens back the browser and clicks on restore pages and comes to the same page, this approach does not work. It only works if user closed the tab or refreshed the tab.

The solution [in this link](http://jasonjl.me/blog/2015/06/21/taking-action-on-browser-crashes/) does not work for multiple tabs. I was looking at service worker but I am new to the concept. Will they help? Or any other approach helps in this case? I am trying to solve this problem on the client side. Is this possible or should I use a combination of backend and frontend for this?

Comment: If you add a timestamp alongside the process ids in localStorage you can check for stale data

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Comment: You need a way for jobs to timeout in your queue, and also be able to do healthchecks of your jobs. For example you could have created_at/updated_at timestamps in the local storage. Each minute you could update the updated_at timestamp if your job is still running. And you could check the local storage to see if the current job (index 0) is stuck/has crashed by comparing the updated_at with the current time, if it's too old, like for example 2 minutes, you could discard it or try to resume it.